SCSS/SASS compilation error with OpenCart 3.0.4.0 and PHP 8.0
My OpenCart 3.0.4.0 install has been working fine with PHP 8.0 for quite a while. I was making some changes to the view and refreshed the theme and SASS cache. The theme refresh worked fine, but the SASS refresh throws an error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ScssPhp\ScssPhp\Compiler::compileString() in /Users/seb/Projects/shop/admin/controller/startup/sass.php:17 
Stack trace: 
#0 /Users/seb/Projects/shop/system/storageundh3m8jmtxd/modification/system/engine/action.php(79): ControllerStartupSass->index() 
#1 /Users/seb/Projects/shop/system/engine/router.php(67): Action->execute(Object(Registry)) 
#2 /Users/seb/Projects/shop/system/engine/router.php(46): Router->execute(Object(Action)) 
#3 /Users/seb/Projects/shop/system/framework.php(179): Router->dispatch(Object(Action), Object(Action)) 
#4 /Users/seb/Projects/shop/system/startup.php(104): require_once('/Users/seb/Proj...') 
#5 /Users/seb/Projects/shop/admin/index.php(19): start('admin') 
#6 {main} thrown in /Users/seb/Projects/shop/admin/controller/startup/sass.php on line 17

This error is preventing me from accessing the OpenCart admin dashboard.
Can anyone explain what has gone wrong and how I can fix it?

Please keep in mind that PHP 8.0 is heavily outdated. Also, if you haven't written any code regarding that stack trace, please report this error to the maintainers of OpenCart

I have also tried this with PHP 8.4 and the issue is unchanged.

You need to move system/storage directory from 3.0.4 to your current storage directory location.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
